# How to monkey patch a React module from Clojurescript

Tags: javascript, clojurescript, monkeypatching

I'm using `react-select` in a ClojureScript project but there is an hardcoded string that I'd like to translate (see it [here](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/blob/e0ccbb939b706dcd560ad34223ab57e20cf0dc49/src/Creatable.js#L218)):

```
function promptTextCreator (label) {
    return `Create option "${label}"`;
}
```

I'll send a PR to make this string configurable but in the meantime I have a question.

If I inspect my app from the JS console, I can type:

```
> window.deps["react-select"]["Creatable"].promptTextCreator
```

which prints

```
ƒ c(e){return'Create option "'+e+'"'}
```

Now in my cljs project I tried this:

```
(set! (.-promptTextCreator Creatable) #(str "TESTING " % "!"))
```

What is interesting is that I can see the change in the app since:

```
> window.deps["react-select"]["Creatable"].promptTextCreator
```

now prints

```
ƒ (p1__44104_SHARP_){
    return [cljs.core.str("TESTING "),cljs.core.str(p1__44104_SHARP_),cljs.core.str("!")].join('');
}
```

Problem: my app still displays the old unchanged string. I also tried to name the new function with:

```
(set! (.-promptTextCreator Creatable) (fn c [e] (str "TESTING " e "!")))
```

and

```
> window.deps["react-select"]["Creatable"].promptTextCreator
```

now prints:

```
ƒ club$views$c(e){
    return [cljs.core.str("TESTING "),cljs.core.str(e),cljs.core.str("!")].join('');
}
```

But no luck: the old untranslated string is displayed in the app.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The `promptTextCreator` is a property, you can pass in your custom function. why need monkey patch?

Comment: Indeed. I discovered this some days later. But you don't answer my question! Thanks for helping though.